# How to add code that will run on visiting a URL, in addition to another module that also has code that will run on same URL, & control execution order

Tags: routes, 9

I'd like to make a custom module that runs code when a URL is visited and then allows an existing module with code that also runs on same URL.

So in the case of the existing module that runs on the URL, it is not affected by my module. That existing module still runs as it would in any case.

I would like my module to run first before the other module.

I'm already familiar with making a custom module and with routine, for example here: [How do I run PHP code when visiting a specific URL?]][1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257462/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-visiting-a-specific-url)

And I've seen this other answer: [Override specific routing from a core module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241880/override-specific-routing-from-a-core-module) But this seems to *replace* the routing of another module and I don't want to do that as said, I want my module to also run on the same URL as another module and be able to control my module running before the other. Thank you.

One thought I have so far: is the execution order of modules controlled by their order in `core.execution.yml` config file?

**Background:**

I want to run code on a callback method at the end of a 3rd-party login authentication. I believe that the callback might be a GET or POST and I'd like my code to read the values of the GET (param) or POST (form submission values) and just pass the URL call back and these intact to the original module, so it processes them as it wants as if my module hadn't looked at them in the first place.

I want my module to look at the data in the callback as GET or POST to decide what role to give the user that's been created and what Drupal Group for it to make to belong to, as a result of the data from the 3rd party authentication.

Comment: It really depends what behaviour of that module you're trying to change/supplement

Comment: @Clive updated the question with background. See also Linked questions on left. Thank you.